# Approximation Algorithms for the Longest Simple Path in a Directed Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-traversal, polynomial-approximations

I am implementing a new approximation algorithm for finding the longest simple path in a directed, unweighted graph from a starting node s to a destination node t. I would like to compare my algorithm's speed to other approximation algorithms for this problem. I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find open source code for these algorithms.

The articles I see online for this problem are purely mathematical/complexity theory analysis of these algorithms with no implementation.